# Unable to send message response back to content script in Chrome Extension using Manifest V3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, sendmessage, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm successfully launching a **webauthflow** to an social OAuth provider from a service worker background script (as per manifest v3 requirements, background scripts are now full blown service workers)

However I'm unable to send a message back to my content script in what should be the simplest scenario.

Here is my service worker (**background.js**)

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.message === "login") {
        if (user_signed_in) {
            console.log("already signed in");
        } else {
            chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
                url: createOAuthEndpoint(),
                interactive: true,
            }, function (redirect_uri) {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    sendResponse({
                        message: "fail"
                    });
                } else {
                    if (redirect_uri.includes("error")) {
                        sendResponse({
                            message: "fail"
                        });
                    } else {
                        //we get here but this message is never sent
                        sendResponse({
                            message: "success",
                            profile: "blah"
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

And here is my content script...(**popupsignin.js**)

```js
document.querySelector('#sign-in').addEventListener('click', () =>  {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: 'login' }, (response) =>  {
        console.log('got the response'); //this log is never written
        if (response.message === 'success'){ 
            console.log(response.profile);            
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The message-related code is correct so the problem is elsewhere. Use devtools to set breakpoints in the callbacks inside the background worker and see what happens when the message is received.

Comment: Yes, so it turns out there was nothing wrong with code as you said.

There was just nowhere for me to read the console.log(...) output in the callback method. I added an alert instead and it fired just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with code. There was(is) just nowhere for me to read the console.log(...) output in the callback method for some reason. I added an alert instead and it fired just fine.